# background-color not showing up on <div> in DocuSign but shows up when exporting to PDF

Tags: docusignapi

I have a div inside my HTML document for responsive signing:

```
<div class="header" style="line-height: 30px; font-size: 1em; background-color: #f9f9f9; padding: 37px 60px;"></div>
```

The color does NOT show up inside DocuSign's view, but when I export the document as a PDF, it shows up there just fine.

I have also tried background, with no success either.

This link says that background-color is supported.
https://developers.docusign.com/docs/esign-rest-api/esign101/concepts/responsive/setting-tabs/

EDIT:
Sorry, I might have been as clear as I should have. Here is a better example of the code I am trying to run:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
      <meta charset="UTF-8">
    </head>
    <body style="font-family: sans-serif; padding: 0px; margin: 0px; font-size: 12px; padding: 0px; color: #11263c;">
        <div class="header" style="line-height: 30px; font-size: 1em; background-color: #f9f9f9; padding: 37px 60px;"> 
            Some other divs with content are here...images, text, etc.
        </div>
        <div class='some-other-content-div'>Blah</div>
        <div class='some-other-content-div-2'>Blah</div>
    </body>
</html>
```

The div with the class **header** is the one that is not showing the color behind it and its children. The value of "pink" worked and its HEX value, the color WHiteSmoke and its HEX (#F5F5F5) worked as well...but not the color GhostWhite or its HEX value (#F8F8FF) or the color I actually want to use...#F9F9F9. Just examples of colors I have tried...I hope this clarifies a bit more!

Comment: Oh darn. I just tested with "pink" instead of a HEX value...and it works fine. I tried RGB value and that didn't work either. Probably should be a note in the documentation I linked above about only supporting browser color names.

Comment: Just tried GhostWhite as a value but that doesnt work either, so now I'm a little confused on whats going on...

Answer (score 1):

This may be a bug, which I'll ask to be fixed.
From what I can tell, it's dropping empty divs until it finally gets to some content. Including any visible elements before their div, or an invisible div with content `"<div style='display:none'>.</div>"`, seems to get it working correctly.
So this is the workaround for now.

Comment: See edit to question above. Side note, I notice you work for docusign, do  you have an official bug tracking system for users, unable to find one.

Comment: Sorry, Inbar. I think I wasn't clear. My div does have content inside of it (more divs). I have updated my original question with more clarification. Let me know if you have anymore questions.

Comment: https://feedback.docusign.com/forums/936834-apis use this to report issue

Comment: Thank you, Inbar. Would you prefer I move my questions there? I have this one and another I opened up here on SO.

Comment: I saw both your questions, you can certainly post in both places.